# Kafka schema evolution

Tags: apache-kafka, avro

Is the schema backward compatible when we change the namespace of the schema and evolve it? The Landoop UI says its backward compatible when we change the namespace to a new one but could not find this in Avro's [rules](http://avro.apache.org/docs/1.7.7/spec.html#Schema+Resolution)

Ex:
Old schema 
"namespace":"com.xxx.yyy.zzz.a" 
Evolved schema 
"namespace":"com.abc.xxx.yyy.zzz.a"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Namespace" similar to "doc", is an optional string that qualifies the name;

Thus by the specification I speculate that it's usage is mostly decorative/descriptive, and evolutions rules are ok with changes in descriptive fields (i.e. the 'doc' field).

It does affect things, i.e. if you are using the schema to generate the classes, the namespace will be affected, but in terms of old or future consumers it should not really affect them. please correct me if the above is not accurate